# How get access to input form dynamic create form in Zend

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I tried build form for a list of books. And i want make to update every quantity position in every row. I thought i can create dynamic form with one field like quantity.

```
$zendFormUpdate = new Zend_Form;
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
    $quantity[$i] = $this->addElement('text','quantity'.$i,[
        'required' => false,
     ]);
}
$this->view->forms = ['formupdate' => $zendFormUpdate];
```

And now i would like ask you, how can i get this fields ?
I am using code below but i can't get anything

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
        <form>
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){ ?>
            <?php echo $this->forms['formupdate']->quantity.$i; ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </form>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
// note the s after ->form, as well
$this->forms['formupdate']->getElement( 'quantity' . $i );
```

But since it's a typographical error, this:

```
$this->forms['formupdate']->{ 'quantity' . $i };
```

should work as well. I forgot you could access `Zend_Form` elements in this manner too.

Comment: Yes $this->forms['formupdate']->getElement( 'quantity'.$i ) works perfect for me THANK YOU

Comment: @user4347073 You're welcome! I missed the `$i` at first. I've added those, so now you can see how to use the `$i` in the alternative syntax, as well.

Comment: yes yes it is ok now. Thx bro u saved my time i tried figure out from yesterday :)